# Use a QrBarcode in Delphi 7 via FastReport

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastreport

Hi whom to be concerned

I need to use QRBarcode in a project , is written by Delphi7 and I use Fastreport. But I don't have  QRBarcode component in FastReport. How can  I install it?
Thank you

Comment: QRBarcode  is for QuickReports, which is not FastReport. You'll need to search for a third-party component that works with FastReport. (This is not the site to ask for someone to recommend one for you.)

Answer (score 0):

FR5 VCL have QR barcode support. Use TfrxBarcodeView object

Comment: FR5 VCL have 2D barcodes support. Download FR trial for D7 and test it
2D barcodes doesn't available in the FR 5 VCL Embarcadero Edition only, but FR 5 VCL Embarcadero Edition doesn't available for D7

Comment: Merci. But I have FR4.7.9 and I can't change it by some reason. I should find another way.